# Unable to pass value to "test_size" dynamically in train_test_split function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have following python code.

```
size = 0.25

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1,test_size= size )
```

when it get executed , I am getting following error

```
raise ValueError("Invalid value for test_size: {}".format(test_size)) ValueError: Invalid value for test_size: 0.25
```

How to pass test size dynamically to train_test_split function in python.

Comment: Remove the space before `size`

Comment: it worked , Now I need to pass it as variable using class member class LearningModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prediction_accuracy = 0
        self.select_query = ''
        self.predict_select_query = ''
        self.update_query_label = ''
        self.update_query = ''
        
        self.testsize = ''
  
  
  
 def buildAndTest(self):
 ...
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1,test_size=self.testsize)
 
 
 
 



if __name__ == "__main__":
 lm = LearningModel()
 lm.testsize = 0.25
 lm.buildAndTest()

Comment: Sorry I'm not following. You need to pass X_train and X_test into the model?

Comment: I have figured it out ZWang. Thanks for you help.